# How to use BuildBlockerProperty on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've tried to use the Pipeline Syntax Code Generator from Jenkins.
It produces an `property` block when executed retrieves an error, `property` is not supported by Pipeline.

Tried to convert the [BuildBlockProperty](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/build-blocker-plugin/) code generated to `option` still not working.

I like the feature as deliver by Build Blocker Plugin and I would like to use the same way on Pipeline.
Block the entire pipeline on a queue while other jobs (concurrent or prioritized) are being executed.

With the Lockable Resources there are parts of the pipeline that starts filling the executors.

Answer (score 1):

with this PR (https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-blocker-plugin/pull/19) merged it will be more simple :)
such as this

```
pipeline {
agent any

options {
  buildBlocker (useBuildBlocker: true, blockLevel: 'NODE', scanQueueFor: 'ALL', blockingJobs: 'foo-.*')
}   
....
```

}

Comment: Olivier Lamy, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: It might be a good idea to include an example how this could be done when the PR is merged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
properties([
  [
    $class         : 'BuildBlockerProperty',
    blockLevel     : 'GLOBAL',
    blockingJobs   : '<your-regex>',
    scanQueueFor   : 'DISABLED',
    useBuildBlocker: true
  ],
])
```

Source: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/

You can also generate the snippet from Jenkins itself. Just create a new pipeline Job, and will find a configuration menu entry called "Pipeline Syntax" > "Snippet Generator" und select as Sample Step "properties: Set Job Properties"

See also: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/

Answer (score 0):

This problem plagued me as well.  After a lot of searching, I found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/N0LanJpGTc8

The short of it is when using the declarative pipeline you must wrap the use of `properties` in a `script` step.  The advice above was to put this in the steps of one of the stages.  This worked for me.  I then experimented and discovered I was able to put a `script` step at the top level before the `pipeline` step.  The result was the same in both cases.  The build of my multibranch project stayed in the queue until the BuildBlocker condition was satisfied.  Here is an example of my Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy

script {
    // Use BuildBlocker to wait for all 'comps' projects to finish building
    properties([
        [$class: 'BuildBlockerProperty', blockLevel: 'GLOBAL', blockingJobs: 'comps-.*', scanQueueFor: 'ALL', useBuildBlocker: true]
    ])
}

pipeline {
    // the usual pipeline sections and steps
}
```